# Flink Watermark latency with PromQL

Tags: apache-flink, prometheus, prometheus-alertmanager, promql

So I want to alert when my watermark falls behind.

I want to use metrics reported by flink's job manager. Something like this, but this doesnt work as I like it.

```
(timestamp(flink_taskmanager_job_task_operator_currentInputWatermark{task_name=~"my_window.*"})-(4*60*60*1000))-flink_taskmanager_job_task_operator_currentInputWatermark{task_name=~"my_window.*"}
```

Verbally : i'd like to get a diff in currentTime (time when the metric was reported) - wmatermark ts.

`(4*60*60*1000)` is to convert to EDT -- is there a better way to do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. so the above query was almost perfect. what I was doing wrong is shifting an already EDT timestamp to -4h. Below is the perfect query to do this:

```
timestamp(flink_taskmanager_job_task_operator_currentInputWatermark{task_name="my_window",job_name="session"})*1000-flink_taskmanager_job_task_operator_currentInputWatermark{task_name="my_window",job_name="session"}
```

the `flink_taskmanager_job_task_operator_currentInputWatermark` reports doesnt report in ms but `timestamp` does hence the `*1000` conversion